# Laravel stripping data pulled from database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have some data in my database formatted with several tabs between bits of information like so:

"921      N".

When laravel retrieves this information from the database, the tabs are stripped away and replaced with a single space, such as:

"921 N".

Here is the code I am using to retrieve the info from the database:

`$receipt = \App\class::join('table1','table2.table1_id', '=','table1.id')->where(function($query)use($id){$query->where('table1.id', '=', $id+1);})->get();`

When displaying the text, it is simply being returned, nothing else is acting upon it.
My question is how do I avoid stripping the extra tabs and spaces away so the information can be displayed properly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're displaying the text in a webpage.

By default, browsers condense all consecutive whitespace down to one space. So, the data is probably being retrieved from the database correctly, but the browser is not showing it how you like.

If you want to show the data exactly as it is, you can wrap it in `<pre></pre>` tags.